# Combine 2 df by columns name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Helo!

I have loaded a few datasets, the only thing in common is that they have the same Columns names BUT, the number of columns/rows and the data are different , so looks like i cannot use merge or concat because there is not thing in common by ID for example.. I want to to put each df above the other and leave the "extra" columns with Nan values.

df1:
| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| ID 1   | Cell 2   |
| ID 2   | Cell 4   |

df2:

| Column A | Column B | ColumnC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID 3 | Cell 2 | info |
| ID 4 | Cell 4 | info |

I wanto something like this:

df:

| Column A | Column B | ColumnC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID 1 | Cell 2 | Nan |
| ID 2 | Cell 4 | Nan |
| ID 3 | Cell 2 | info |
| ID 4 | Cell 4 | info |

Thanks a lot for your time!

I have try something like df = pd.concat(['df1','df2'], axis=1) and merge

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2])` would do exactly what you're describing. Please provide an example that illustrates what *doesn't* work with `pd.concat`, ideally share it in a form that can be copied and pasted, like the output of `df.to_dict(orient="list")`.

Comment: @fsimonjetz i just saw mi problem i tried 'df1' instead of df1  XD Thanks!!